# Using just Javascript, how can I prevent a disabled form element from output?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to take my form which outputs to a text area on the same page and have it only show any enabled fields. You can see it at my [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/66qpfyhh/), Right now, when you click the "Combine" button it outputs all 4 categories even though two are disabled by default.

So it will output:

```
Optional Detail: 
Default Detail: 
Optional Selection: 
Default Selection:
```

But I want it to look like this if the details toggles are unchecked:

```
Default Detail: 
Default Selection:
```

Here's my script:

```
function convertForm() {
var detailToggle = document.getElementById("detailToggle").value;
var basicDetail = document.getElementById("basicDetail").value;
var selectOne = document.getElementById("selectOne").value;
var selectTwo = document.getElementById("selectTwo").value;

var output = "";

output += "Optional Detail: " + detailToggle + "\n";
output += "Default Detail: " + basicDetail + "\n";
output += "Optional Selection: " + selectOne + "\n";
output += "Default Selection: " + selectTwo + "";
document.getElementById("output3").value = output;
}

function toggle(checkboxID, toggleID) {
var checkbox = document.getElementById(checkboxID);
var toggle = document.getElementById(toggleID);
updateToggle = checkbox.checked ? toggle.disabled=false : 
toggle.disabled=true;
}

function ResetForm() {
document.getElementById("detailToggle").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("selectOne").disabled = true;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<table width="100%" height=" " border="0"><tr>
<td width=550 valign=top>

<form name="Form3" onsubmit="return false;" action="">
Toggle detail:
<input type="checkbox" id="ChecktoggleDetail" class="formArea" 
name="Toggledetail" onClick="toggle('ChecktoggleDetail', 'detailToggle')">
<input type="text" class="formArea" name="details"
id="detailToggle" placeholder="Toggle field" disabled required>
<br>
Detail:
<br>
<input type="text" class="formArea" name="Basicdetail" id="basicDetail"
placeholder="Some detail" maxlength="25" required>
<br>
Selection 1:
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckselectOne" class="formArea" 
name="detailsgiven"  onClick="toggle('CheckselectOne', 'selectOne')">
<br>
<select type="drop" class="formArea" name="Selectone" id="selectOne" 
disabled required>
<option value="" disabled selected>...</option>
<option value="Option One">Option 1</option>
<option value="Option Two">Option 2</option>
</select>
<br>
Selection 2:
<br>
<select type="drop" class="formArea" name="Selecttwo" id="selectTwo" 
required>
<option value="" disabled selected>...</option>
<option value="Option One">Option 1</option>
<option value="Option two">Option 2</option>
</select>
<br>

</td>
<td valign="top">
<table border="0" height="200" ><tr><td valign="top" height=200>

<textarea type="textarea" class="formArea" name="form3output" id="output3"
onclick="this.focus();this.select()" cols="70" rows="10" placeholder="" 
required></textarea><br>
</td></tr>

<tr><td valign=top>
<div class="btn-group">
<button value="Combine" onclick="convertForm()" 
id="combine3">Combine</button>
</div>
<br>

<div class="btn-group2">
<button type="reset" value="Reset form" onclick="ResetForm();">Reset 
form</button> <br> 
</div>
</form>

</td></tr></table>
```

I am still new to Javascript, I am guessing there is some variable to insert, but am not sure what it is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Store the output rows in an array, and iterate through the array, and check, if the corresponding element is disabled. If it is, exclude the row from the final output.

Comment: You can check the disabled property of html element by element.disabled. It will return true and false. If it is true then don't include it in your textarea code.

Comment: Here you are directly printing the statement you have to write some if condition and validate if it is disabled=true then print null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You May Try For This:

Here I just check the **disabled property of the element**, if element is not disabled then i added text to output,

```
function convertForm() {
var detailToggle = document.getElementById("detailToggle").value;
var basicDetail = document.getElementById("basicDetail").value;
var selectOne = document.getElementById("selectOne").value;
var selectTwo = document.getElementById("selectTwo").value;
debugger;
var output = "";
if(!document.getElementById("detailToggle").disabled){
output += "Optional Detail: " + detailToggle + "\n";
}
if(!document.getElementById("basicDetail").disabled){
output += "Default Detail: " + basicDetail + "\n";
}
 if(!document.getElementById("selectOne").disabled){
    output += "Optional Selection: " + selectOne + "\n";
}
 if(!document.getElementById("selectTwo").disabled){
    output += "Default Selection: " + selectTwo + "";
}



document.getElementById("output3").value = output;
}

function toggle(checkboxID, toggleID) {
var checkbox = document.getElementById(checkboxID);
var toggle = document.getElementById(toggleID);
updateToggle = checkbox.checked ? toggle.disabled=false : toggle.disabled=true;
}

function ResetForm() {
document.getElementById("detailToggle").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("selectOne").disabled = true;
}
```

For More info visit me on:
https://jsfiddle.net/66qpfyhh/8/

Comment: Perfect that works great, exactly what I was looking for, thanks man :)

Answer (score 2):

Use below javascript to check element is  disabled first then append  in variable

Check updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh078/66qpfyhh/1/

```
function convertForm() {
    var detailToggle = document.getElementById("detailToggle");
    var basicDetail = document.getElementById("basicDetail");
    var selectOne = document.getElementById("selectOne");
    var selectTwo = document.getElementById("selectTwo");

    var output = "";

    if (!detailToggle.disabled) {
        output += "Optional Detail: " + detailToggle.value + "\n";
    }
    if (!basicDetail.disabled) {
        output += "Default Detail: " + basicDetail.value + "\n";
    }
    if (!selectOne.disabled) {
        output += "Optional Selection: " + selectOne.value + "\n";
    }
    if (!selectTwo.disabled) {
        output += "Default Selection: " + selectTwo.value + "";
    }

    document.getElementById("output3").value = output;

}

function toggle(checkboxID, toggleID) {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById(checkboxID);
    var toggle = document.getElementById(toggleID);
    updateToggle = checkbox.checked ? toggle.disabled = false : toggle.disabled = true;
}

function ResetForm() {
    document.getElementById("detailToggle").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("selectOne").disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, this works great as well, I was surprised to see three answers to quickly, Appreciate everyone taking a few minutes to help :)

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet can solve your problem.

```js
function convertForm() {
    var detailToggle = document.getElementById("detailToggle").value;
    var basicDetail = document.getElementById("basicDetail").value;
    var selectOne = document.getElementById("selectOne").value;
    var selectTwo = document.getElementById("selectTwo").value;
  
    if(document.getElementById("detailToggle").disabled)
     detailToggle='';
    if(document.getElementById("selectOne").disabled)
     selectOne='';
    var output = "";
    
    output += "Optional Detail: " + detailToggle + "\n";
    output += "Default Detail: " + basicDetail + "\n";
    output += "Optional Selection: " + selectOne + "\n";
    output += "Default Selection: " + selectTwo + "";
    document.getElementById("output3").value = output;
    }
    
    function toggle(checkboxID, toggleID) {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById(checkboxID);
    var toggle = document.getElementById(toggleID);
    updateToggle = checkbox.checked ? toggle.disabled=false : toggle.disabled=true;
    }

    function ResetForm() {
    document.getElementById("detailToggle").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("selectOne").disabled = true;
    }
```

```html
<table width="100%" height=" " border="0"><tr>
    <td width=550 valign=top>

    <form name="Form3" onsubmit="return false;" action="">
    Toggle detail:
    <input type="checkbox" id="ChecktoggleDetail" class="formArea" 
    name="Toggledetail" onClick="toggle('ChecktoggleDetail', 'detailToggle')">
    <input type="text" class="formArea" name="details"
    id="detailToggle" placeholder="Toggle field" disabled required>
    <br>
    Detail:
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="formArea" name="Basicdetail" id="basicDetail"
    placeholder="Some detail" maxlength="25" required>
    <br>
    Selection 1:
    <input type="checkbox" id="CheckselectOne" class="formArea" 
    name="detailsgiven"  onClick="toggle('CheckselectOne', 'selectOne')">
    <br>
    <select type="drop" class="formArea" name="Selectone" id="selectOne" disabled               required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>...</option>
    <option value="Option One">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option Two">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Selection 2:
    <br>
    <select type="drop" class="formArea" name="Selecttwo" id="selectTwo" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>...</option>
    <option value="Option One">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option two">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <br>

    </td>
    <td valign="top">
    <table border="0" height="200" ><tr><td valign="top" height=200>

    <textarea type="textarea" class="formArea" name="form3output" id="output3"
    onclick="this.focus();this.select()" cols="70" rows="10" placeholder="" required>           </textarea><br>
    </td></tr>

    <tr><td valign=top>
    <div class="btn-group">
    <button value="Combine" onclick="convertForm()" id="combine3">Combine</button>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="btn-group2">
    <button type="reset" value="Reset form" onclick="ResetForm();">Reset form</button> <br> 
    </div>
    </form>

    </td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Thanks man, that works too, the only thing I noticed as an issue was that with this method, if one of the fields is enabled, and the others still disabled, it will still output all 4 categories instead of just 3. Still, it gets me closer than I was before.

Comment: I didn't get you.

Comment: It's all good man, like I said, it was still getting me closer than not. :)